# Can't figure out how to move this text over

Tags: windows-phone

I'm having an extremely difficult time trying to line up the text in the image that you see. My code for the design is below and for the life of me, I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone please point me in the right direction? I'm terrible with design layouts but good in coding so I would appreciate any help.

[image: current design look]

```
<controls:PivotItem Header="Top 10 Picks">
            <Grid Name="gridStocks">
                <Grid.Resources>
                    <Style x:Key="LabelStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15,5" />
                    </Style>
                    <Style x:Key="ValueStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15,5" />
                    </Style>
                    <Style x:Key="HeaderStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                    </Style>
                    <Style x:Key="SummaryStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
                        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Right" />
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="15,0,0,0" />
                    </Style>
                    <Style x:Key="NumberStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="FlowDirection" Value="LeftToRight" />
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="9.5" /> 
                    </Style>
                    <Style x:Key="ListBoxStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Setter Property="Background" 
                        Value="{StaticResource PhoneSemitransparentBrush}" />
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3,5" />
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" 
                        Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderBrush}" />
                        <!-- Replace the default item template with a basic template
               that does not highlight selected items. -->
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <ContentPresenter/>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </Grid.Resources>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}" Text=" " />
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}" Text="Symbol" />
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}" Text="Rating" />
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}" Text="Est. Return" />
                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10,45" Height="758" Grid.Column="0">
                    <TextBlock Text="1." Style="{StaticResource NumberStyle}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="2." Style="{StaticResource NumberStyle}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="3." Style="{StaticResource NumberStyle}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="4." Style="{StaticResource NumberStyle}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="5." Style="{StaticResource NumberStyle}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="6." Style="{StaticResource NumberStyle}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="7." Style="{StaticResource NumberStyle}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="8." Style="{StaticResource NumberStyle}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="9." Style="{StaticResource NumberStyle}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="10." Style="{StaticResource NumberStyle}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>

                <ScrollViewer Margin="-5,13,3,36" Height="558">
                    <ListBox ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle}" Name="lstTop10Picks" Height="480" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5,25,0,0" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="444" Grid.Column="1">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SummaryStyle}" 
                                    Text="{Binding Symbol}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SummaryStyle}" 
                                    Text="{Binding ShortRating}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SummaryStyle}" 
                                    Text="{Binding LongRating}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
        </controls:PivotItem>
```

Comment: make the padding element all to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created this
[image: Like this]

with the following XAML:

```
<phone:PivotItem Header="Top 10 Picks">
    <Grid Name="gridStocks">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="HeaderStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="SummaryStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Left" />
                <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="NumberStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="FlowDirection" Value="LeftToRight" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="9.5,0" />
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}" Grid.Column="1" Text="Symbol" />
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}" Grid.Column="2" Text="Rating" />
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}" Grid.Column="3" Text="Est. Return" />

        <ScrollViewer Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Row="1">
            <ItemsControl Name="lstTop10Picks">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="6">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource NumberStyle}" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Id}" />
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SummaryStyle}" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Symbol}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SummaryStyle}" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding ShortRating}" />
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SummaryStyle}" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding LongRating}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</phone:PivotItem>
```

Here's a quick summary of what I changed:

- Stop trying to pad strings (TextBlocks) to make them line up. **Just put everything in a grid**!
- Put the numbers (Ids) and the data in the same dataset. This is much simpler than trying to line up the contents of a stack panel and a list.
- Used an ItemsControl rather than a ListBox as didn't need the ListBox specific features.
- Note the first column in the grid is half the width of the others.
- Got rid of the ScrollViewer. Not needed as everything fits on the screen. You doubly didn't need it previously as the ListBox contains one internally so contents would have scrolled without it.
- By having no margins within the grid I was able to use the same ColumnDefinitions in the ItemTemplate and still have everything line up.

I tested with this as the datasource:

```
this.lstTop10Picks.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Pick>
{
    new Pick { Id = 1, Symbol = "CHGS", ShortRating = "-81.433", LongRating = "-51.804" },
    new Pick { Id = 2, Symbol = "CWTR", ShortRating = "-12.345", LongRating = "-12.345" },
    new Pick { Id = 3, Symbol = "CBSTZ", ShortRating = "-12.345", LongRating = "-12.345" },
    new Pick { Id = 4, Symbol = "CBMXW", ShortRating = "-12.345", LongRating = "-12.345" },
    new Pick { Id = 5, Symbol = "UNTK", ShortRating = "-12.345", LongRating = "-12.345" },
    new Pick { Id = 6, Symbol = "TVIX", ShortRating = "-12.345", LongRating = "-12.345" },
    new Pick { Id = 7, Symbol = "UVXY", ShortRating = "-12.345", LongRating = "-12.345" },
    new Pick { Id = 8, Symbol = "NEWL", ShortRating = "-12.345", LongRating = "-12.345" },
    new Pick { Id = 9, Symbol = "TBBK", ShortRating = "-12.345", LongRating = "-12.345" },
    new Pick { Id = 10, Symbol = "PGRX", ShortRating = "-58.856", LongRating = "-52.914" },
};

internal class Pick
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public string ShortRating { get; set; }
    public string LongRating { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would set the width for the textblock that you bind to so they are a uniform size not dependent on the content to set the width